# python pandas - Transform df to get list of names that share one or more attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Starting from a pandas DataFrame (df) as below:

```
Name AttributeList
A      1;2
B      2;3;1
C      4;7
D      8;7;3
```

I want to create a new df for each possible pair of Names, by counting how many attributes they share and skip the case where they share none of the attributes. Following is the expected output:

```
Name1 Name2 NumberAttributesShared
A       B      2
B       D      1
C       D      1
```

Pairs should not be repeated, so if I have A B, then I should not have B A.
In this example, the pair A C is not listed, as A and C do not share any attribute. The pair A B, on the other hand, has value 2 as they share two attributes.

Any clever and efficient way to reach this goal?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Some for cycles, working on lists of lists. But nothing that really worked, in less than infinite time for large datasets. I need help :)

Comment: Anky because they share no attributes. I don't need that rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have duplicate ids, the straightforward solution is the following

```
z = list(zip(names, map(set, atts.str.split(';').tolist())))

dict_ = dict()

for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(z)):
        inter = (z[i][1].intersection(z[j][1]))
        if inter:
            dict_[(z[i][0], z[j][0])] = len(z[i][1].intersection(z[j][1]))

pd.DataFrame(dict_, index=['NumberAttributesShared']).T.reset_index()
```

Of course, in pure python and not taking advantage of any library as `itertools`. You get the idea, may try on some improvements

```
level_0 level_1 NumberAttributesShared
0   A   B       2
1   B   D       1
2   C   D       1
```

Since we're working with loops and collections of `str` and `set`, you most probably don't want to use `pandas` for this. Work in pure python and input your output in a `pd.DataFrame` in the end

Comment: Thanks Rafael. What is the starting command if my input is a DataFrame named df? Also using a library as itertools would be ok, if it can improve performance on large dataframes. I tried a double for cycle in the past with the intersection command, but with 800,000 rows it was taking hours.

Comment: `names` is `df.names and `atts` is `df.AttributeList`. I understand your performance issues but as is now, your problem seems to be `O(n^2)` by nature. Maybe if you added more information, e.g. how you construct the `df` in the first place, or any other restrictions that might reduce dimensionality ?

Comment: The df is unfortunately given as I showed it to you. So performance remains an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Start from generating an additional column, a copy of `AttributeList`,
but as a **list** of attributes (instead of a string or int):

```
df['AttrList'] = df.AttributeList.astype(str).str.split(';')
```

Then, to speed up reading of individual elements, copy `Name` to index:

```
df.set_index('Name', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Then you can compute the number of common attributes for each 2-element
combination of names:

```
lst = []
for names in itertools.combinations(df1.Name, 2):
    n1, n2 = names
    s1 = set(df.at[n1, 'AttrList'])
    s2 = set(df.at[n2, 'AttrList'])
    cnt = len(s1.intersection(s2))
    if cnt > 0:
        lst.append([n1, n2, cnt])
```

And finally you can generate the result:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['Name1', 'Name2', 'NumberAttributesShared'])
```

Of course, you should start from `import itertools`.

## Edit

Your example data contained **only** strings with separated with ";".
Now, as you indicated that the attribute list can contain a **single** number,
I realized that the type of an individual field can be either `string` or
`int`.

To properly read the attributes in both cases, in `df['AttrList'] = ...`
instruction change the right-hand side to:

```
df.AttributeList.astype(str).str.split(';')
```

(added `.astype(str)` to convert to the right type, I changed this detail
also above).

## How to solve the performance issue

A hint (but not the full solution) how to speed up the calculation.

Genarate an auxiliaty table:

```
dfSgl = df[df.AttributeList.astype(str).str.isdigit()]
```

containing only rows with a **single** attribute.

My example data contain four rows with a single attribute:

```
['E', 2], ['F', 3], ['G', 4], ['H', 4]
```

So in my case `dfSgl` contains:

```
     Name AttributeList
Name                   
E       E             2
F       F             3
G       G             4
H       H             4
```

Then execute:

```
dfSgl.groupby('AttributeList').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)
```

getting in this case:

```
     Name AttributeList
Name                   
G       G             4
H       H             4
```

This means that both `G` and `H` have **one** common attribute (4).

This is probably not the final result for these objects,
as their (single) attribute can occur in attribute lists of other
objects with **multiple** attributes.

Then you have to compare the above "singles" with other objects
with **multiple** attributes, maybe adding some common attributes
to their account.

The remaining part is to compare only objects with multiple attributes,
as I explained at the beginning and join the results. So at least
the dimension of the problem will be smaller.

## Edit as of 9.02.2019

My first solution was based solely on Pandas, but it turned out it works
relatively slow.

So I came up with another, much quicker solution, based on Numpy and Pandas.

The idea is:

1. Set the *Name* column as the index of *df*:

   ```
   df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
   ```
2. Add *Attr* column to *df*, containing a **list of numbers** (attributes):

   ```
   df['Attr'] = df.AttributeList.astype(str).str.split(';')\
       .map(lambda x: sorted(pd.to_numeric(x)))
   ```

It will be needed to compute the attribute vector for each object.

3. We need an auxiliary function:

   ```
   def genAttrList(lst, len):
       res = np.zeros(len, dtype='B')
       for n in lst:
           res[n] = 1
       return res
   ```

to generate an attribute vector, with ones on positions corresponding to
attributes (numbers) from *lst*. The second parameter (len) specifies the
length of this vector - max. attribute + 1 (element 0 is not used).

Note **dtype='B'** (unsigned byte), based on assumption that the number
of attributes is less than 256. It lowers memory requirements, compared
to default (in this case) **int** type.

4. The function computing the solution is:

   ```
   def fun3(df):
       ind = df.index
       attrLen = df.Attr.map(lambda x: x[-1]).max() + 1
       attr = np.array(df.Attr.transform(lambda x:
           genAttrList(x, attrLen)).tolist())
       counts = np.count_nonzero(np.bitwise_and(
           attr[np.newaxis, :], attr[:, np.newaxis]), axis=(2))
       return pd.DataFrame(data=[ (ind[x[0]], ind[x[1]], counts[x])
           for x in zip(*np.nonzero(np.triu(counts, 1)))],
           columns=['Name1', 'Name2', 'NumberAttributesShared'])
   ```

The first part is to compute *attr* array (2-D). Each row represents data
for particular user - an attribute list encoded as a sequence of zeroes and ones.

Then *counts* array is computed as follows:

- *bitwise_and* is computed for two instances of *attr* with additional
  axis in various places. Actually the *and* is computed for every
  possible pair of objects.
- Then (on the result of the previous step) there is computed
  *count_nonzero*, counting how many attributes has in common each
  pair of objects.

The power of this solution results from:

- The fact that *bitwise_and* is an **universal function**, which runs much
  quicker than "ordinary" Python functions.
- Numpy **broadcasting**, which is very efficient technique with little
  memory requirements.
- Using of added axes, allowing to perform computation on each pair of
  objects from a list.

The last step is to compute (and return) the actual result (DataFrame).
The points worth to note are:

- *triu* returns *counts* array with zeroed elements on the main
  diagonal and below.
- *nonzero* returns **indices** of non-zero elements in the above array.
- This way we get indices of non-zero elements from the upper triangle
  of *counts* (above the main diagonal).
  This limitation allows to avoid duplicates with "swapped" object labels.
- *zip* creates an iterator returning row / column pairs.
- *ind[x[0]* and *ind[x[1]* translates array coordinates to object names.
- *counts[x]* reads the corresponding element from *counts* (the number
  of common attributes).

So the only remainig thing is to call:

```
result = fun3(df)
```

I compared the execution time with my initial solution (using *%timeit*),
on a sample data of 500 objects with up to 5 attributes from a list of 50,
and it turned out that this solution is about 10 times quicker.

Initially I proposed to perform separate computation for objects with
a single attribute, then each single with each multiple and finally
each with each object with multiple attributes (function *fun2* not
included here).
But it turned out that this solution works about 2.5 times longer than
*fun3*, so I revoke this proposition.

If you want to compare this result with the result of computation performed
with another method, use the following "ordering function":

```
def ordered(df):
    res = df.copy()
    res[['Name1', 'Name2']] = np.sort(res[['Name1', 'Name2']].values, axis=1)
    return res.sort_values(['NumberAttributesShared', 'Name1', 'Name2'],
        ascending=[False, True, True]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It swaps *Name1* with *Name2* if they are not in order and sorts rows on
*NumberAttributesShared* (descending), then on both names.
The last step is to reset index.

So you should (for each result) call:

```
ordResult = ordered(result)
```

Having such ordered results from various methods (*ordResult* and
*ordAnotherResult*), you can check whether they are the same:

```
ordResult.equals(ordAnotherResult)
```

And the last note: I am fully aware that this edit contains much new
information, especially from the *Numpy* area.
But don't feel intimidated with this "avalanche" of new concepts.
Take each issue which is new or little known to you, one by one,
and search the Web for further explanations.

Comment: This solution works great! However, in all cases where I have only one attribute (which python reads as a number even if it is a label), the command df['AttrList'] = df.AttributeList.str.split(';') generates NaN, instead of copying that single attribute. The solution which seems to work is to force the attributes column to string first: df['AttributeList'] = df['AttributeList'].astype(str)

Comment: Only performance remains an issue. The loop is running since 30 min, with a df of 300,000 rows. Don't know how long it will take.

Comment: As Rafael commented, the complexity of this computation is O(n^2). I'm afraid there is no quicker solution using any interpreted language. Maybe you should try to solve the problem using e.g.Java or C++?

Comment: Thank you Valdi! I'm eager to try the solution with performance improvement. Could you give me the full code, so I can test it on my large df? I'm not sure I totally understood the process, but with the full code I could try.

Comment: What I added recently, is only what I think how it can be done. I have no working code. The task is too big.